# Передать значение переменных из одной функции в другую

Tags: python

как передать значения x_list, y_list из функции get_data_plot в функцию plot, внутри одного класса, чтоб построить график??

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
        # инициализация GUI
        ...

    def get_data_plot(self):        
            url = 'https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price'
            params = {'timespan': '10year', 'rollingAverage': '8hours', 'format': 'json'}
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            data = response.json()
    
            x_list = []
            y_list = []
            for item in data["values"]:
                x_list.append(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(item['x']))
                y_list.append(item['y'])
            return x_list, y_list
    
        
    def plot(self, x_list, y_list):
            ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            ax.plot(x_list, y_list)
            self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: насколько я понимаю, всё это - класс. так .. укажите его, а то двусмысленно

Comment: добавил класс, весь GUI не добавлял - думаю бессмысленно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Вызов внутри класса

Если вам надо вызывать функции класса внутри класса, то вам надо написать что-то такое:
`self.<имя функции>(<аргументы функции>)` т.е. всё тоже самое, как с обычными функциями, только добавить `self.` впереди.
Пример:

```py
class Foo:
  def print_test(self):
    print("test")

  def call_print_test(self):
    self.print_test()  # вызов функции внутри класса
```

---

## Вызов снаружи класса

Если же вы хотите вызвать функции класса снаружи класса, то вам надо будет написать что-то такое:
`<имя экземпляра класса>.<имя функции>(<аргументы функции>)`.
Пример:

```py
class Foo:
  def print_test(self):
    print("test")

bar = Foo()  # экземпляра класса Foo, имя - bar
bar.print_test()  # вызов функции вне класса
```

Т.к. у функции `print_test` аргументов нет, то мы просто пишем `()` для вызова

---

## Пример реализации

Cоответственно, в зависимости от того, что вы хотите получить, вам надо написать либо `self.plot(self.get_data_plot(<аргументы функции>))` либо `<имя экземпляра класса>.plot(<имя экземпляра класса>.get_data_plot(<аргументы функции>))`.

Я бы это положил в функцию, чтобы получилось:

```py
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...

    def get_data_plot(self):
        ...
        return x_list, y_list

    def plot(self, x_list, y_list):
        ...

    def create_plot(self):
        self.plot(*self.get_data_plot())


window = MainWindow()
window.create_plot()  # создаётся график
```

Также не проблема вызвать `create_plot` внутри класса (`self.create_plot()`)

---

## Дополнительная информация

В функции `create_plot` я также использовал распаковку с помощью
`*`, т.е. `get_data_plot` выводит кортеж, и чтобы "раскрыть" его в две переменные, как того требует `plot`, мы используем `*`.

Вот [доки питона](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) об этом.
И [статья на русском](https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/), для удобства.

Больше информации о классах вы можете увидеть в [документации питона](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)
Если вам тяжело работать с английский языком, то вам [вводная статься о классах на русском](https://codecamp.ru/blog/python-classes/)

---

### Ремарка

По-хорошему `функции класса` надо называть `методами`, но я опустил это в ответе, для простоты понимания.

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, если вам помог этот ответ, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

вообще-то это самые азы любого языка, но если вы просите именно так, то

```
plot(get_data_plot())
```

Comment: это первое что я сделал, но это происходит внутри класса. Вызываю внутри класса и получаю ошибку: TypeError: get_data_plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, вам стоит обратить внимание на ошибки, они существуют как раз для вас  :) попробуйте их переводить хотя бы. Да и загуглить ошибку - тоже отличная практика. Если вкраце, то вы забыли `self.` перед вызовом метода класса, т.е. надо `self.get_data_plot()`

Comment: plot(self.get_data_plot()) -->> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Значит не надо self 

Comment: plot(get_data_plot(self))

Comment: гадание на кофейной гуще?

Comment: На кофейной гуще гадает тот, кто не читает ошибок.

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто такой вариант не работает. Или я уже не то чёт делаю

Comment: какая ошибка при таком варианте - ``plot(get_data_plot(self))``?

Comment: @Эникейщик  NameError: name 'self' is not defined  -> откуда вызывать?

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, вы не проанализировали, почему возникла ошибка? если вам надо вызвать эти две функции внутри класса, то надо для них обоих добавить `self.`, чтобы получилось так: `self.plot(self.get_data_plot())`.

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, а вообще, это не то чтобы, какая-то ошибка, а незнание синтаксиса языка. [в документации питона](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) всё отчетливо расписано и показано. И в следующий раз вам в первую очередь надо идти гуглить, искать в документации, на stack overflow, и уже если ничего не получается, то задать вопрос, где описать, что пробовали и что не получилось

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, а в качестве метода для поиска ошибок вам стоит предпринять здесь довольно простые действия: попробовать отдельно вызвать две функции перед их совмещением в одну строку. Вам сразу бы стало ясно, что в обоих случаях что-то не работает. Когда же вы вызываете их в одной строке, вам труднее это понять.

Comment: @ДенисБудяк, `plot(self.get_data_plot()) -->> NameError: name 'self' is not defined` - судя по этой ошибке, вы вызываете эти методы не из методов класса (где `self` доступен), значит нужно вызывать их не от self, а от объекта этого класса, т.е. что-то типа `window.plot(*window.get_data_plot())` - вместо `window` укажите переменную, в которую у вас записан объект `MainWindow`

Comment: @ДенисБудяк вашу проблему решает [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257348/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e/1257952#1257952)?

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант:

```py
a, b = get_data_plot()
plot(a, b)
```

или сразу вызвать в функции

```py
def get_data_plot(self):        
        # Ваш код...
        self.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете определить переменные `x_list, y_list`как атрибуты класса, далее доставать их в функциях используя атрибут класса `self`.

Пример кода класса, который вы можете использовать.

```
class ClassName:
    x_list = []  # ваши переменный в области видимости имен класса
    y_list = []  

    def get_data_plot(self):
        ...  
        self.x_list.append('some data')  # тут добавляете элемент в список
        self.y_list.append('some data')

    def plot(self, x_list, y_list):
        ...
        ax.plot(self.x_list, self.y_list) 
        ...
```

... - часть кода не переписывал

Comment: добавил инициализацию класса в первом посте, глобальные переменные как-то не хотел использовать

Comment: Я исходил из вашего вопроса, задавайте вопрос более конкретно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну может тогда так:

```
def plot(self):
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x_list, y_list = self.get_data_plot()
        ax.plot(x_list, y_list)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Вы вообще где и как этот `plot` вызываете?

Comment: Функция подвязана к кнопке в инициализации GUI.

Comment: Вот ошибка TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_list'